# GAE-NDB: how prevent projection changed the results

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I used [ndb projection](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#projection) but it did change the results, how the results are not affected by projection?

```
class T(ndb.Model):
  name = ndb.StringProperty()  
  name2 = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)

  @classmethod
  def test(cls):
    for i in range(0, 10):
      t = T(name=str(i))
      if i%2 == 0:
        t.name2=["zzz"]      
      t.put()

    qr = T.query()
    qo = ndb.QueryOptions(projection=['name', 'name2'])
    items, cursor, more = qr.fetch_page(20, options=qo)
    print len(items)

    qo = ndb.QueryOptions(projection=['name'])
    items, cursor, more = qr.fetch_page(20, options=qo)
    print len(items)
```

The result is 5, 10

How to make result is 10, 10 ?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, Tim Hoffman is wrong. The answer below is correct.

Comment: Have deleted my comment, don't want any one to be mislead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An empty list-property (repeated=True) won't get indexed and as it's the index that projection queries use to return results, entities without values for the property won't be returned.
Your test case *is* susceptible to the eventual-consistency that Tim's comment mentions, but it isn't the only issue.